# add cakephp named parameters to url on list select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

let's say I have a select list as follows:

```
<select name='languages'>
    <option value='german'>German</option>
    <option value='english'>English</option>
</select>
```

How do I, with javascript/jQuery refresh the page when the user selects a language and add a [Named parameter style](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/947/Named-parameters/) parameters to the end of my url every time the user smakes a choice, for example, if the user selects german, the url should look like:

```
http://my_app/my_controller/my_action/language:select_option_value_for_german
```

If the user selects english, the url will be:

```
http://my_app/my_controller/my_action/language:select_option_value_for_english
```

So, everytime the user makes a selection, the same page is refreshed with the named parameters added at the end of the url.

**NOTE** : I want the named parameters to appear only once per request, in other words, I don't want them to repeat at the end of the url like:

```
http://my_app/my_controller/my_action/language:select_option_value_for_german/language:select_option_value_for_english
```

Any help is very appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your js file listen to change event on your select and build the url and navigate to the built url.

```
$('select[name="languages"]').change(function(){
    var url ="/my_app/my_controller/my_action/language:" + $(this).val();
    window.location = url;
});​​​
```

Change your selectbox with default value, for you to select the German in every refresh. I miss to notice that every refresh the default is german that is why you always get english

```
<select name='languages'>
    <option>Select language</option>
    <option value='german'>German</option>
    <option value='english'>English</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does not work, the named parameters stack up at the end everytime I make a selection, also, the selection is not preserved in the list after the page refresh

Comment: it work on my test using cake2.0. edited the code the url part.

Comment: The problem was that I was using `$this->Html->url( null, true );` to get the current url, the reason why the parameters were repeated at the end was because they were included in the current url everytime I make a request. Is there any way I can remove the parameters from the url using a cakePHP or PHP function or something  or do I have to use regex for that?

Comment: Seems `parse_url()` won't work for `named` parameters. You can use regex

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="language"]').on('change', function() {
    var pn = window.location.protocol +
             window.location.hostname +
             window.location.pathname +
             window.location.hash;
    window.location.assign(pn + '?language=' + $(this).val());
});
```